# Is a large credit limit on a credit card dangerous if credit card details are hacked and leaked?

Tags: credit-card, security, singapore, credit-limit

Suppose the bank got hacked and credit card details are leaked to hackers. Is it dangerous to have a large credit limit because hackers may use the credit card to go on a spending spree? Would it be advisable to cut down credit limit to reduce money lost due to spending sprees by hackers? Am I being unduly worried?

Assume the credit card is issued in Singapore.

Comment: I don't know about Singapore (which is why this is not an answer), but in the US you're not responsible for any fraudulent use of your card, regardless of how much is spent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The credit limit is not going to be the problem; the daily spending limit is more likely be tripped first.
I'm not a lawyer but if you are not responsible for the credit card details being leaked it is very unlikely that the bank will be able to charge you for fraudulent spending on the card.

The important thing is to notify the bank as soon as possible once you realize there is a problem and if practical keep evidence of that notification, it will then be the banks problem to fix. From my understanding Singapore has relatively good consumer protection and it is unlikely the bank will get very far even if they try to charge you.